# /bin/sh: 0: Can't open ROOT=$(dirname $0)/

Tags: ubuntu, sh

I am trying to run a simple batch script I created, but there seems to be something wrong (which I cant figure out yet).

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh ROOT=$(dirname $0)/..
PYTHON=$ROOT/env/bin/python3 ODOO=$ROOT/src/odoo/odoo-bin
$PYTHON $ODOO -c $ROOT/projectname.cfg "$@" exit $?
```

When I make the script executable, and run the script at the command line `bin/odoo`, I get the following error message:

> /bin/sh: 0: Can't open ROOT=$(dirname $0)/..

Unfortunately, `man dirname` does not shed much light on what could be going wrong. How do I fix the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the shebang `#! /bin/sh` you have to insert a linebreak. Otherwise the literal string `ROOT=$(dirname $0)/..` is interpreted as an argument to `sh` which interprets its first argument as a file to execute. Since there is no file with the literal name `ROOT=$(dirname $0)/..` you get the error message `Can't open ...`.

This isn't the only place where you are missing linebreaks (or `;` instead). Especially the `exit` should have its own line. But actually you can just drop it because `exit $?` is the default behavior at the end of a shell script.

By the way: Special variables and environment variables are ALLCAPS by convention. Use lowercase variable names to avoid accidential name collisions.

```
#!/bin/sh
root=$(dirname "$0")/..
python=$root/env/bin/python3
odoo=$root/src/odoo/odoo-bin
"$python" "$odoo" -c "$root/projectname.cfg" "$@"
```

Comment: What about the last line when the script returns with the exit code? Is that superfluous?

Comment: Yes, as I said, the last line `exit $?` is not needed. `sh` does this by default.